# Change the default size of http binding - question about

Tags: wcf

I change the http binding buffer size to be maximum possible.

```
 <binding name="LargeData_basicHttpBinding" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
              maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
                  maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
          </binding>
```

In case my server receive need to send some buffer size with less then 2147483647 bytes - Is the service will use always 2147483647 byte size in the buffer ?

If the answer is 'no' so why not define always buffer size to be 2147483647 - and the framework will use the minimum size that need for sending the buffer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure in answer at your first question, but limitation are used for prevent performance issue and last but not least security (DDOS attacks).